# Grouping and Summarising in a MySQL Query

Tags: mysql

I've run a MySQL query (this is in wordpress php):

```
$myQuery = $wpdb->get_results('SELECT Opponent, ROUND(AVG(Avg_Points),2) 
AS Avg_Points, ROUND(AVG(Plus_Minus),2) AS Avg_Plus_Minus 
FROM ' . 'afl_defense_v_position' . ' WHERE Position = "MID" 
AND Rank <= 1 AND Round >= 10 GROUP BY Opponent 
ORDER BY Avg_Plus_Minus DESC')
```

I'm now wondering how to get the Average and Standard Deviation of the resulting `Avg_Plus_Minus` column and `Avg_Points` column.

I can easily get the average and standard deviation of `Plus_Minus` and `Average` before I've grouped these but how do I go about this after grouping? I'm aware the average is the same but the standard deviation isn't.

I'm wanting to assign these values to php variables for further analysis.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Do you need to show the totals row also? If yes you need a union all.

Comment: No, I'm just wanting the standard dev and average of the grouped data, so basically two values

Answer (score 0):

A simple nested MySQL query worked here

```
$myQuery = $wpdb->get_results('SELECT STDDEV(t.Avg_Points) AS Std_Points 
FROM (SELECT Opponent, ROUND(AVG(Points),2) AS Avg_Points, 
ROUND(AVG(Plus_Minus),2) AS Avg_Plus_Minus FROM ' . 
'afl_defense_v_position' . ' WHERE Position = "'. $select.'" 
AND Rank <= '. $select3.' AND Round >= '. $select4.' 
GROUP BY Opponent) AS t');
```